# Extended Kalman Filter prediction Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, prediction, matlab-cvst, kalman-filter

I'v implemented *EKF (Extended Kalman Filter)* in *Matlab* for *Visual Tracking* of Object's 3D trajectory, However, I'm giving it actual trajectory's position and velocity as `in1` and `in2` respectively. I'm facing wrong prediction after some points which is usually opposite to the actual trajectory. What I think, it may be some initial assumptions problem as I'v checked the equations many times but unable to find the bug. How to fix my initial assumptions or to avoid by any other guesses? Sample position and velocity are given.
Any suggestions for improving my approach are welcomed.

**My Code:**

```
function EKF(in1,in2)
ind=0; % indicator function. Used for unwrapping of tan
[H] = [];
[K] = [];
[Z] = [];
Q=[0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0.01 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0.01 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0.01];% Covarience matrix of process noise
M=[0.001 0 0; 0 0.001 0; 0 0 0.001]; % Covarience matrix of measurment noise
A=[1 0 0 0.1 0 0;
    0 1 0 0 0.1 0;
    0 0 1 0 0 0.1;
    0 0 0 1 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 1]; % System Dynamics
in = cat(2,in1,in2);
X(:,1)=in(1,:)'; % Actual initial conditions

 Z(:,1)=X(1:3,:);% initial observation
Xh(:,1)=X(:,1);%Assumed initial conditions
P(:,:,1)=[0.1 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0.1 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0.1 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0.1 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0.1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0.1]; %inital value of covarience of estimation error

%  plots
subplot(3,3,1)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('X')
title('X possition')
hold on
subplot(3,3,4)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('Y')
title('Y possition')
hold on
subplot(3,3,7)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('Z')
title('Z possition')
hold on
subplot(2,2,2)
xlabel('time')
title('Minimum MSE')
hold on
subplot(2,2,4)
plot3(0,0,0)
title('3-D trajectory ')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
zlabel('Z')
hold on
for n=1:100
    %% PROCESS AND OBSERVATION PROCESS WITH GAUSSINA NOISE
    X(:,n+1)=A*X(:,n)+[0;0;0;sqrt(Q(4,4))*randn(1);sqrt(Q(5,5))*randn(1);sqrt(Q(6,6))*randn(1)]; % State process % w generating process noise
    Z(:,n+1)=[sqrt(X(1,n)^2+X(2,n)^2);arctang(X(2,n),X(1,n),ind);X(3,n)]+[sqrt(M(1,1))*randn(1);sqrt(M(1,1))*randn(1);sqrt(M(1,1))*randn(1)]; %generating & observation observation noise
    %% prediction of next state
    Xh(:,n+1)=A*Xh(:,n);% ESTIMATE
    P(:,:,n+1)=A*P(:,:,n)*A'+Q;% PRIORY ERROR COVARIENCE
    %% CORRECTION EQUTIONS
    H(:,:,n+1)=[Xh(1,n+1)/(sqrt(Xh(1,n+1)^2+Xh(2,n+1)^2)), Xh(2,n+1)/(sqrt(Xh(1,n+1)^2+Xh(2,n+1)^2)),0,0,0,0; ...
        -Xh(2,n+1)/(sqrt(Xh(1,n+1)^2+Xh(2,n+1)^2)), Xh(1,n+1)/(sqrt(Xh(1,n+1)^2+Xh(2,n+1)^2)),0,0,0,0; ...
        0,0,1,0,0,0]; % Jacobian matrix
    K(:,:,n+1)=P(:,:,n+1)*H(:,:,n+1)'*(M+H(:,:,n+1)*P(:,:,n+1)*H(:,:,n+1)')^(-1); % Kalman Gain

    Inov=Z(:,n+1)-[sqrt(Xh(1,n+1)^2+Xh(2,n+1)^2);arctang(Xh(2,n+1),Xh(1,n+1),ind);Xh(3,n+1)];% INNOVATION
    Xh(:,n+1)=Xh(:,n+1)+ K(:,:,n+1)*Inov; %computes final estimate
    P(:,:,n+1)=(eye(6)-K(:,:,n+1)*H(:,:,n+1))*P(:,:,n+1);% %computes covarience of estimation error
    %% unwrapping the tan function
    theta1=arctang(Xh(1,n+1),Xh(2,n+1),0);
    theta=arctang(Xh(1,n),Xh(2,n),0);
    if abs(theta1-theta)>=pi
        if ind==1
            ind=0;
        else
            ind=1;
        end
    end
    %% Some Plots
    subplot(3,3,1)
    line([n,n+1],[X(1,n),X(1,n+1)])
    hold on
    drawnow
    subplot(3,3,4)
    line([n,n+1],[X(2,n),X(2,n+1)])
    hold on
    drawnow
    subplot(3,3,7)
    line([n,n+1],[X(3,n),X(3,n+1)])
    hold on
    drawnow

    subplot(2,2,4)
    line([Xh(1,n) Xh(1,n+1)],[Xh(2,n) Xh(2,n+1)],[Xh(3,n) Xh(3,n+1)],'Color','r')
    hold on
    drawnow
    line([X(1,n) X(1,n+1)],[X(2,n) X(2,n+1)],[X(3,n) X(3,n+1)])
    hold on
    drawnow
    subplot(2,2,2)
    line([n,n+1],[(X(1,n)-Xh(1,n))^2,(X(1,n+1)-Xh(1,n+1))^2])
    hold on
    drawnow
    line([n,n+1],[(X(2,n)-Xh(2,n))^2,(X(2,n+1)-Xh(2,n+1))^2],'Color','r')
    hold on
    drawnow
    line([n,n+1],[(X(3,n)-Xh(3,n))^2,(X(3,n+1)-Xh(3,n+1))^2],'Color','c')
    hold on
    drawnow
    legend('X-MSE','Y-MSE','Z-MSE')

    subplot(3,3,1)
    line([n,n+1],[Xh(1,n),Xh(1,n+1)],'Color','r')
    hold on
    drawnow
    subplot(3,3,4)
    line([n,n+1],[Xh(2,n),Xh(2,n+1)],'Color','r')
    hold on
    drawnow
    subplot(3,3,7)
    line([n,n+1],[Xh(3,n),Xh(3,n+1)],'Color','r')
    hold on
    drawnow
end
%% arctang
function   [ARG]=arctang(A,B,ind)
if B<0 && A>0 % PLACING IN THE RIGHT QUADRANT
ARG=abs(atan(A/B))+pi/2;
elseif B<0 && A<0
ARG=abs(atan(A/B))+pi;
elseif B>0 && A<0
ARG=abs(atan(A/B))+3*pi/2;
else
ARG=atan(A/B);
end
if ind==-1 % UNWARPPING PART
ARG=ARG-2*pi;
else
if ind==1;
ARG=ARG+2*pi;
end
end
end
end
```

**in1 - position of object**

```
  -21.8318   19.2251  -16.0000
  -21.4604   18.9727  -15.8555
  -21.0925   18.7208  -15.7102
  -20.7281   18.4693  -15.5639
  -20.3671   18.2182  -15.4169
  -20.0093   17.9676  -15.2692
  -19.6547   17.7173  -15.1208
  -19.3031   17.4674  -14.9717
  -18.9545   17.2178  -14.8221
  -18.6088   16.9687  -14.6719
  -18.2658   16.7198  -14.5213
  -17.9255   16.4714  -14.3702
  -17.5879   16.2232  -14.2187
  -17.2528   15.9755  -14.0669
  -16.9203   15.7281  -13.9147
  -16.5901   15.4811  -13.7623
  -16.2623   15.2345  -13.6097
  -15.9368   14.9883  -13.4569
  -15.6135   14.7425  -13.3040
  -15.2925   14.4971  -13.1509
  -14.9735   14.2522  -12.9978
  -14.6567   14.0078  -12.8446
  -14.3420   13.7638  -12.6914
  -14.0292   13.5204  -12.5383
  -13.7185   13.2776  -12.3852
  -13.4097   13.0353  -12.2322
  -13.1028   12.7936  -12.0793
  -12.7979   12.5525  -11.9266
  -12.4948   12.3122  -11.7741
  -12.1935   12.0725  -11.6218
  -11.8941   11.8336  -11.4697
  -11.5965   11.5954  -11.3179
  -11.3007   11.3581  -11.1663
  -11.0067   11.1216  -11.0151
  -10.7144   10.8860  -10.8642
  -10.4240   10.6513  -10.7137
  -10.1353   10.4176  -10.5635
   -9.8483   10.1850  -10.4138
   -9.5631    9.9533  -10.2644
   -9.2797    9.7228  -10.1155
   -8.9980    9.4934   -9.9671
   -8.7181    9.2652   -9.8191
   -8.4399    9.0382   -9.6717
   -8.1636    8.8125   -9.5247
   -7.8890    8.5882   -9.3783
   -7.6162    8.3652   -9.2325
   -7.3452    8.1436   -9.0872
   -7.0760    7.9234   -8.9424
   -6.8087    7.7048   -8.7983
   -6.5432    7.4877   -8.6548
   -6.2795    7.2723   -8.5119
   -6.0178    7.0584   -8.3696
   -5.7579    6.8463   -8.2280
   -5.5000    6.6359   -8.0870
   -5.2440    6.4273   -7.9467
   -4.9899    6.2206   -7.8071
   -4.7378    6.0157   -7.6681
   -4.4878    5.8127   -7.5299
   -4.2397    5.6118   -7.3923
   -3.9938    5.4128   -7.2555
   -3.7499    5.2159   -7.1194
   -3.5080    5.0211   -6.9841
   -3.2684    4.8285   -6.8495
   -3.0308    4.6380   -6.7156
   -2.7955    4.4498   -6.5825
   -2.5624    4.2639   -6.4502
   -2.3315    4.0803   -6.3187
   -2.1028    3.8990   -6.1879
   -1.8765    3.7202   -6.0579
   -1.6525    3.5438   -5.9287
   -1.4308    3.3699   -5.8004
   -1.2115    3.1985   -5.6728
   -0.9946    3.0297   -5.5460
   -0.7801    2.8635   -5.4200
   -0.5681    2.6999   -5.2949
   -0.3586    2.5390   -5.1706
   -0.1516    2.3807   -5.0471
    0.0528    2.2253   -4.9245
    0.2547    2.0725   -4.8027
    0.4539    1.9226   -4.6817
    0.6506    1.7755   -4.5616
    0.8446    1.6313   -4.4423
    1.0358    1.4899   -4.3239
    1.2244    1.3514   -4.2063
    1.4103    1.2159   -4.0897
    1.5934    1.0833   -3.9738
    1.7737    0.9538   -3.8589
    1.9512    0.8272   -3.7448
    2.1258    0.7036   -3.6315
    2.2976    0.5831   -3.5192
    2.4665    0.4657   -3.4077
    2.6326    0.3513   -3.2971
    2.7956    0.2400   -3.1874
    2.9558    0.1318   -3.0786
    3.1130    0.0268   -2.9707
    3.2672   -0.0751   -2.8636
    3.4184   -0.1739   -2.7575
    3.5665   -0.2695   -2.6522
    3.7117   -0.3620   -2.5479
    3.8537   -0.4513   -2.4444
    3.9927   -0.5374   -2.3419
    4.1287   -0.6204   -2.2402
    4.2615   -0.7002   -2.1395
    4.3912   -0.7768   -2.0397
    4.5178   -0.8503   -1.9408
    4.6413   -0.9205   -1.8428
    4.7616   -0.9876   -1.7457
    4.8788   -1.0516   -1.6495
    4.9928   -1.1124   -1.5542
    5.1036   -1.1700   -1.4599
    5.2113   -1.2246   -1.3665
    5.3158   -1.2760   -1.2740
    5.4171   -1.3242   -1.1825
    5.5153   -1.3694   -1.0919
    5.6102   -1.4115   -1.0022
    5.7020   -1.4506   -0.9135
    5.7906   -1.4866   -0.8257
    5.8760   -1.5195   -0.7388
    5.9583   -1.5495   -0.6529
    6.0373   -1.5765   -0.5679
    6.1132   -1.6005   -0.4839
    6.1860   -1.6216   -0.4008
    6.2555   -1.6398   -0.3187
    6.3220   -1.6551   -0.2376
    6.3853   -1.6675   -0.1574
    6.4455   -1.6772   -0.0781
    6.5026   -1.6840    0.0001
    6.5565   -1.6882    0.0774
    6.6074   -1.6896    0.1538
    6.6553   -1.6883    0.2291
    6.7000   -1.6844    0.3035
    6.7418   -1.6779    0.3769
    6.7805   -1.6688    0.4493
    6.8163   -1.6572    0.5207
    6.8491   -1.6431    0.5911
    6.8789   -1.6266    0.6606
    6.9058   -1.6077    0.7290
    6.9298   -1.5865    0.7965
    6.9510   -1.5630    0.8629
    6.9693   -1.5373    0.9283
    6.9847   -1.5093    0.9927
    6.9974   -1.4792    1.0562
    7.0074   -1.4470    1.1185
    7.0146   -1.4128    1.1799
    7.0191   -1.3766    1.2403
    7.0210   -1.3385    1.2996
    7.0203   -1.2985    1.3579
    7.0170   -1.2567    1.4151
    7.0111   -1.2132    1.4714
    7.0027   -1.1679    1.5265
    6.9919   -1.1210    1.5807
    6.9786   -1.0726    1.6338
    6.9629   -1.0226    1.6858
    6.9449   -0.9712    1.7368
    6.9246   -0.9184    1.7867
    6.9020   -0.8642    1.8356
    6.8773   -0.8088    1.8834
    6.8503   -0.7522    1.9301
    6.8212   -0.6945    1.9758
    6.7901   -0.6357    2.0204
    6.7569   -0.5759    2.0639
    6.7218   -0.5152    2.1064
    6.6847   -0.4536    2.1478
    6.6458   -0.3912    2.1881
    6.6050   -0.3280    2.2273
    6.5625   -0.2643    2.2654
    6.5183   -0.1999    2.3024
    6.4723   -0.1350    2.3383
    6.4248   -0.0696    2.3732
    6.3757   -0.0039    2.4069
    6.3251    0.0622    2.4396
    6.2731    0.1285    2.4711
    6.2197    0.1950    2.5016
    6.1649    0.2616    2.5309
    6.1089    0.3283    2.5592
    6.0516    0.3949    2.5863
    5.9932    0.4614    2.6124
    5.9337    0.5278    2.6373
    5.8731    0.5940    2.6611
    5.8116    0.6598    2.6839
    5.7491    0.7253    2.7055
    5.6857    0.7904    2.7261
    5.6216    0.8549    2.7455
    5.5566    0.9189    2.7638
    5.4910    0.9823    2.7811
    5.4248    1.0450    2.7972
    5.3579    1.1070    2.8122
    5.2906    1.1681    2.8262
    5.2228    1.2284    2.8391
    5.1546    1.2877    2.8508
    5.0860    1.3461    2.8615
    5.0172    1.4034    2.8712
    4.9481    1.4596    2.8797
    4.8789    1.5146    2.8872
    4.8096    1.5684    2.8936
    4.7402    1.6210    2.8990
    4.6708    1.6722    2.9033
    4.6014    1.7221    2.9066
    4.5322    1.7706    2.9088
    4.4631    1.8176    2.9100
    4.3943    1.8631    2.9102
    4.3257    1.9070    2.9094
    4.2574    1.9494    2.9076
    4.1895    1.9901    2.9047
    4.1221    2.0292    2.9009
    4.0551    2.0666    2.8961
    3.9886    2.1022    2.8904
    3.9226    2.1361    2.8837
    3.8573    2.1682    2.8761
    3.7927    2.1985    2.8676
    3.7287    2.2270    2.8581
    3.6655    2.2536    2.8478
    3.6030    2.2783    2.8365
    3.5414    2.3011    2.8244
    3.4806    2.3221    2.8115
    3.4207    2.3411    2.7978
    3.3618    2.3582    2.7832
    3.3038    2.3734    2.7679
    3.2467    2.3867    2.7517
    3.1907    2.3980    2.7349
    3.1357    2.4075    2.7173
    3.0818    2.4150    2.6990
    3.0290    2.4207    2.6800
    2.9773    2.4245    2.6604
    2.9267    2.4264    2.6401
    2.8772    2.4266    2.6192
    2.8289    2.4249    2.5978
    2.7817    2.4215    2.5758
    2.7358    2.4164    2.5533
    2.6910    2.4095    2.5303
    2.6474    2.4011    2.5068
    2.6049    2.3910    2.4829
    2.5637    2.3794    2.4587
    2.5236    2.3664    2.4340
    2.4846    2.3519    2.4091
    2.4469    2.3361    2.3838
    2.4102    2.3190    2.3584
    2.3747    2.3008    2.3327
    2.3403    2.2814    2.3068
    2.3069    2.2610    2.2808
    2.2746    2.2397    2.2548
    2.2433    2.2175    2.2287
    2.2130    2.1946    2.2026
    2.1836    2.1711    2.1765
    2.1551    2.1472    2.1506
    2.1274    2.1228    2.1248
    2.1006    2.0982    2.0992
    2.0745    2.0735    2.0739
    2.0491    2.0487    2.0489
    2.0243    2.0242    2.0242
    2.0000    2.0000    2.0000
```

**in2 - Velocity of Object**

```
    0.3714   -0.2524    0.1445
    0.3679   -0.2519    0.1454
    0.3644   -0.2515    0.1462
    0.3610   -0.2511    0.1470
    0.3578   -0.2507    0.1477
    0.3546   -0.2503    0.1484
    0.3516   -0.2499    0.1491
    0.3486   -0.2495    0.1496
    0.3457   -0.2492    0.1502
    0.3430   -0.2488    0.1506
    0.3403   -0.2485    0.1511
    0.3376   -0.2481    0.1515
    0.3351   -0.2478    0.1518
    0.3326   -0.2474    0.1521
    0.3302   -0.2470    0.1524
    0.3278   -0.2466    0.1526
    0.3255   -0.2462    0.1528
    0.3233   -0.2458    0.1530
    0.3211   -0.2454    0.1531
    0.3189   -0.2449    0.1531
    0.3168   -0.2444    0.1532
    0.3148   -0.2439    0.1532
    0.3127   -0.2434    0.1531
    0.3107   -0.2429    0.1531
    0.3088   -0.2423    0.1530
    0.3069   -0.2417    0.1529
    0.3050   -0.2410    0.1527
    0.3031   -0.2404    0.1525
    0.3012   -0.2397    0.1523
    0.2994   -0.2389    0.1521
    0.2976   -0.2382    0.1518
    0.2958   -0.2373    0.1515
    0.2940   -0.2365    0.1512
    0.2922   -0.2356    0.1509
    0.2905   -0.2347    0.1505
    0.2887   -0.2337    0.1502
    0.2870   -0.2327    0.1498
    0.2852   -0.2316    0.1493
    0.2834   -0.2305    0.1489
    0.2817   -0.2294    0.1484
    0.2799   -0.2282    0.1480
    0.2781   -0.2270    0.1475
    0.2764   -0.2257    0.1469
    0.2746   -0.2244    0.1464
    0.2728   -0.2230    0.1459
    0.2710   -0.2216    0.1453
    0.2692   -0.2201    0.1447
    0.2673   -0.2186    0.1441
    0.2655   -0.2171    0.1435
    0.2636   -0.2155    0.1429
    0.2618   -0.2138    0.1423
    0.2599   -0.2121    0.1416
    0.2579   -0.2104    0.1410
    0.2560   -0.2086    0.1403
    0.2540   -0.2068    0.1396
    0.2521   -0.2049    0.1389
    0.2501   -0.2030    0.1382
    0.2480   -0.2010    0.1375
    0.2460   -0.1990    0.1368
    0.2439   -0.1969    0.1361
    0.2418   -0.1948    0.1353
    0.2397   -0.1926    0.1346
    0.2375   -0.1904    0.1339
    0.2353   -0.1882    0.1331
    0.2331   -0.1859    0.1323
    0.2309   -0.1836    0.1315
    0.2286   -0.1812    0.1308
    0.2263   -0.1788    0.1300
    0.2240   -0.1764    0.1292
    0.2217   -0.1739    0.1284
    0.2193   -0.1714    0.1276
    0.2169   -0.1688    0.1268
    0.2145   -0.1662    0.1260
    0.2120   -0.1636    0.1251
    0.2095   -0.1609    0.1243
    0.2070   -0.1582    0.1235
    0.2044   -0.1555    0.1226
    0.2019   -0.1527    0.1218
    0.1993   -0.1499    0.1210
    0.1966   -0.1471    0.1201
    0.1940   -0.1442    0.1193
    0.1913   -0.1414    0.1184
    0.1886   -0.1385    0.1176
    0.1858   -0.1355    0.1167
    0.1831   -0.1326    0.1158
    0.1803   -0.1296    0.1150
    0.1775   -0.1266    0.1141
    0.1747   -0.1236    0.1132
    0.1718   -0.1205    0.1123
    0.1689   -0.1175    0.1115
    0.1660   -0.1144    0.1106
    0.1631   -0.1113    0.1097
    0.1601   -0.1082    0.1088
    0.1572   -0.1051    0.1079
    0.1542   -0.1019    0.1070
    0.1512   -0.0988    0.1061
    0.1482   -0.0956    0.1053
    0.1451   -0.0925    0.1044
    0.1421   -0.0893    0.1035
    0.1390   -0.0861    0.1025
    0.1359   -0.0830    0.1016
    0.1328   -0.0798    0.1007
    0.1297   -0.0766    0.0998
    0.1266   -0.0734    0.0989
    0.1235   -0.0703    0.0980
    0.1203   -0.0671    0.0971
    0.1172   -0.0640    0.0962
    0.1140   -0.0608    0.0952
    0.1108   -0.0577    0.0943
    0.1077   -0.0545    0.0934
    0.1045   -0.0514    0.0925
    0.1013   -0.0483    0.0915
    0.0981   -0.0452    0.0906
    0.0950   -0.0421    0.0897
    0.0918   -0.0390    0.0887
    0.0886   -0.0360    0.0878
    0.0854   -0.0330    0.0869
    0.0822   -0.0300    0.0859
    0.0791   -0.0270    0.0850
    0.0759   -0.0240    0.0840
    0.0727   -0.0211    0.0831
    0.0696   -0.0182    0.0821
    0.0664   -0.0153    0.0812
    0.0633   -0.0125    0.0802
    0.0602   -0.0096    0.0792
    0.0571   -0.0069    0.0783
    0.0540   -0.0041    0.0773
    0.0509   -0.0014    0.0763
    0.0478    0.0013    0.0754
    0.0448    0.0039    0.0744
    0.0417    0.0065    0.0734
    0.0387    0.0091    0.0724
    0.0357    0.0116    0.0714
    0.0328    0.0141    0.0704
    0.0298    0.0165    0.0694
    0.0269    0.0189    0.0684
    0.0240    0.0212    0.0674
    0.0211    0.0235    0.0664
    0.0183    0.0258    0.0654
    0.0155    0.0279    0.0644
    0.0127    0.0301    0.0634
    0.0099    0.0322    0.0624
    0.0072    0.0342    0.0614
    0.0045    0.0362    0.0603
    0.0019    0.0381    0.0593
   -0.0007    0.0400    0.0583
   -0.0033    0.0418    0.0573
   -0.0059    0.0436    0.0562
   -0.0084    0.0453    0.0552
   -0.0108    0.0469    0.0541
   -0.0133    0.0485    0.0531
   -0.0157    0.0500    0.0520
   -0.0180    0.0514    0.0510
   -0.0203    0.0528    0.0499
   -0.0226    0.0541    0.0489
   -0.0248    0.0554    0.0478
   -0.0269    0.0566    0.0467
   -0.0291    0.0577    0.0457
   -0.0311    0.0588    0.0446
   -0.0332    0.0598    0.0435
   -0.0351    0.0607    0.0425
   -0.0371    0.0616    0.0414
   -0.0389    0.0624    0.0403
   -0.0408    0.0631    0.0392
   -0.0425    0.0638    0.0381
   -0.0443    0.0644    0.0370
   -0.0459    0.0649    0.0359
   -0.0475    0.0654    0.0348
   -0.0491    0.0657    0.0337
   -0.0506    0.0661    0.0326
   -0.0520    0.0663    0.0316
   -0.0534    0.0665    0.0305
   -0.0548    0.0666    0.0294
   -0.0560    0.0667    0.0283
   -0.0573    0.0666    0.0271
   -0.0584    0.0665    0.0260
   -0.0595    0.0664    0.0249
   -0.0606    0.0661    0.0238
   -0.0616    0.0659    0.0227
   -0.0625    0.0655    0.0216
   -0.0634    0.0651    0.0205
   -0.0642    0.0646    0.0194
   -0.0649    0.0640    0.0183
   -0.0656    0.0634    0.0172
   -0.0663    0.0627    0.0161
   -0.0668    0.0620    0.0150
   -0.0673    0.0611    0.0140
   -0.0678    0.0603    0.0129
   -0.0682    0.0593    0.0118
   -0.0685    0.0583    0.0107
   -0.0688    0.0573    0.0096
   -0.0691    0.0562    0.0086
   -0.0692    0.0550    0.0075
   -0.0693    0.0538    0.0064
   -0.0694    0.0526    0.0054
   -0.0694    0.0512    0.0043
   -0.0693    0.0499    0.0033
   -0.0692    0.0485    0.0022
   -0.0691    0.0470    0.0012
   -0.0689    0.0455    0.0002
   -0.0686    0.0440   -0.0008
   -0.0683    0.0424   -0.0018
   -0.0679    0.0407   -0.0028
   -0.0675    0.0391   -0.0038
   -0.0670    0.0374   -0.0048
   -0.0665    0.0357   -0.0057
   -0.0659    0.0339   -0.0067
   -0.0653    0.0321   -0.0076
   -0.0647    0.0303   -0.0085
   -0.0640    0.0285   -0.0095
   -0.0632    0.0266   -0.0103
   -0.0624    0.0247   -0.0112
   -0.0616    0.0228   -0.0121
   -0.0608    0.0209   -0.0129
   -0.0599    0.0190   -0.0138
   -0.0590    0.0171   -0.0146
   -0.0580    0.0152   -0.0154
   -0.0570    0.0133   -0.0161
   -0.0560    0.0114   -0.0169
   -0.0550    0.0094   -0.0176
   -0.0539    0.0076   -0.0183
   -0.0528    0.0057   -0.0190
   -0.0517    0.0038   -0.0196
   -0.0506    0.0020   -0.0203
   -0.0495    0.0001   -0.0209
   -0.0483   -0.0017   -0.0214
   -0.0471   -0.0034   -0.0220
   -0.0460   -0.0051   -0.0225
   -0.0448   -0.0068   -0.0230
   -0.0436   -0.0085   -0.0235
   -0.0424   -0.0100   -0.0239
   -0.0413   -0.0116   -0.0243
   -0.0401   -0.0131   -0.0246
   -0.0389   -0.0145   -0.0250
   -0.0378   -0.0158   -0.0252
   -0.0366   -0.0171   -0.0255
   -0.0355   -0.0183   -0.0257
   -0.0344   -0.0194   -0.0259
   -0.0334   -0.0204   -0.0260
   -0.0323   -0.0213   -0.0261
   -0.0313   -0.0222   -0.0261
   -0.0303   -0.0229   -0.0261
   -0.0294   -0.0235   -0.0260
   -0.0285   -0.0240   -0.0259
   -0.0276   -0.0244   -0.0258
   -0.0268   -0.0246   -0.0256
   -0.0261   -0.0247   -0.0253
   -0.0254   -0.0247   -0.0250
   -0.0248   -0.0245   -0.0247
   -0.0243   -0.0242   -0.0242
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Comment: First suggestion, don't index into matrixes that store history, for your predictor/corrector calculations.  Use a variable for "current state", "current Kalman gain", etc.  That will simplify all the equations a lot.  Then copy these into a history matrix at the end of each timestep.

Comment: nice suggestion, what about the prediction error ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm facing prediction error, What to do ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't understand very well, plz explain how to store in a `variable` instead of Matrix?